# Pythonic use of class and module methods

Tags: python, methods, coding-style, code-readability

I suppose this is a bit of a beginner's question, but I'm wondering about the more pythonic approach to use when you're presented with a situation where you're using class methods from a class defined in a module, as well as methods defined within the module itself.  I'll use numpy as an example.

```
import numpy as np

foo = np.matrix([[3, 4], [9, 12]])

# Get norm (without using linalg)
norm = np.sqrt(foo.dot(foo.T)).diagonal()
```

I can use a mixed case, like this, where I'm calling methods of foo and methods defined in numpy, or I can write the code as below:

```
norm = np.diagonal(np.sqrt(np.dot(foo, foo.T)))
```

I would prefer using foo.bar.baz.shoop.doop syntax, myself, but in this case I can't, as sqrt isn't a method of foo.  So, what would be the more pythonic way to write a line like this?

Incidentally, as a side-question, are class methods usually more optimized, compared to methods defined in a module?  I don't understand too well what's going on under the hood, but I assumed (again using numpy as an example) that numpy has an np.dot method that is written for the general case where arg can be an array or a matrix, while np.matrix.dot is reimplemented and optimized only for matrix operations.  Please correct me if I'm wrong in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions you're asking don't really have an answer, because the case you're asking about simply doesn't exist.

Typically, in Python, you do not have the same function available as a method and as a global function.

NumPy is a special case, because some, but not all, top-level functions are also available as methods on the appropriate object. Even then, they often don't have the same semantics, so the answer isn't a question of style, but of which one is the right function.

For example, in your case, the only one you have a choice on is `diagonal`. And the two options give different results.

```
>>> m = matrix([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> np.diagonal(m)
array([1, 5, 9])
>>> m.diagonal()
matrix([[1, 5, 9]])
```

The module function takes a 2D array of shape (N, N) and returns a 1D array of shape (N,). The method takes a 2D matrix of shape (N, N) and returns a 2D matrix of shape (1, N).

It's possible that the `matrix` method will be faster. But that's not as important as the fact that if one of them is correct, the other one is wrong. It's like asking whether `+` or `*` is a faster way to multiply two numbers. Whether `+` is faster than `*` or not, it's not a faster way to multiply, because it doesn't multiply.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even noticed the different return types.  In truth, this particular example, and a similar one in Theano, were about the only examples I've run into.  It's good to know that this isn't a common issue, then.  It does force me to use the mixed formatting, like in my first example.  I find it a bit more difficult to read without tracking my brackets, but that can be made up for with proper commenting.  Thanks for the answer.
edit: not enough reputation to vote up :(

Comment: @Phox: Remember that you can always fix the brackets problem by using multiple statements, with intermediate variables (`selfdot = np.dot(foo, foo.T)`, then `norm = np.diagonal(np.sqrt(selfdot))`), or by turning complicated expressions into functions (`norm = diagnorm(foo)`).